# How to override to can Subclass of NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, subclass

Does anyone know any way to subclass NSMutableDictionary?

What I want is to have a class which is a subclass of NSMutableDictionary and add some own methods.

I have seen in internet this code: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html

Which is close to what I want, but I need the class to have no properties at all and in the example they use a NSMutableDictionary and a NSMutableArray

Is it possible to override those methods without using any property?

Comment: What kind of methods are you trying to add? Why?

Comment: Methods to get and set information of the properties the NSDictionary will have. I am using Couchbase lite and to embed documents into a document I need an array of dictionaries. This is the reason why I need a class of NSDictionary

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should use Category over NSMutableDictionary and Should Add your own methods than your own methods will be available in NSMutableDictionary class.

For any reference to the category use this link
https://coderwall.com/p/fqnptq